# VSTO support for VS 2015 community edition

Tags: visual-studio, vsto

I have installed `VS 2015 community` `edition`. I am looking forward to develop `outlook add-in` for `outlook 2010` or `on wards`. I can't find any outlook add-in option in project template of VS. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Luckily for you I ran into this recently and found this very helpful page.

[How to install Office Developper Tools for VS Community Edition ?](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/10763/how-to-install-office-developper-tools-for-vs-comm.html) (sic)

1. Download and install [Visual Studio 2015 Update3 Community](https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=visual%20studio%202015)
2. Download and Install [Microsoft Web Platform Installer](https://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx)
3. Open Microsoft Web Platform Installer and search with “Office Tools”
4. Then install Microsoft Office Developer Tools Update2 for Visual Studio 2015

Comment: It looks like since vs 2017 has been made available, no link exist for download of vs 2015 Update3 and etc. Could u plz share the link?

Comment: I'm sure you could google it just as easily as I can. Or use 2017, which probably follows the same install procedure.

Comment: @FIrePanda I've found the link in VS 2015 Extensions and Updates section.